# Please help me transpose the matrix in C (with dynamic memory allocation)

Tags: c, matrix

I have this assignment to get and transpose a matrix using dynamic memory allocation in C

I did it by converting the linear position to (i,j) and swapping i,j
old and new element positions are perfect,
somehow the swap is not working as i intended,
might seem like i'm making others problem solve for me, but i'm blank at this point so help will be really appreciated

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int m,n;
    printf("Enter the order of matrix, m*n:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);

    int *matrix_ptr;
    matrix_ptr = (int *) malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter the elements of %d*%d matrix\n",m,n);
    for(int i=0; i<m*n; i++){
        scanf("%d", matrix_ptr+i);
    }

    // Transposing the matrix

    for(int i=0; i<m*n; i++){
        int i_index = i / n;
        int j_index = i % n;

        // (i_index)*n + j_index gives the linear position

        int new_linear_pos = (j_index)*n + i_index;

        int temp = *(matrix_ptr + new_linear_pos);
        *(matrix_ptr + new_linear_pos) = *(matrix_ptr + i);
        *(matrix_ptr + i) = temp;

        if(i==0){
            printf("\nThe transpose is:\n");
        }
        printf("%d ", *(matrix_ptr+i));
        if((i+1)%n == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are swapping all values twice and you are printing the ones at the beginning of the line after the second swap. The first swap happened with `i` equal `1` and `2`

Let's say you have this matrix at the begin:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

swap index 0 with 0 stays the same thing. Prints `1`

swap index 1 with 3: prints `4`

```
1 4 3
2 5 6
7 8 9
```

swap index 2 with 6: prints `7\n`

```
1 4 7
2 5 6
3 8 9
```

swap index 3 with 1: prints `4`

```
1 2 7
4 5 6
3 8 9
```

etc...

The solution would be to swap elements only once.

The easiest fix would be a `if (i > new_linear_pos) continue; //already swapped`